# Scraping SofaScore votes using Xpath and google sheets

Tags: string, google-sheets, xpath, random

I'm trying to scrape the votes from SofaScore with google sheets using the importxml function.

I'm running into an issue because the class name has a random string at the end of it.

Example "class="sc-5b0433e1-5 **koUsvm**"

Lets use https://www.sofascore.com/washington-nationals-new-york-mets/ExbsFtc as an example link.

Typically I would just use something similar to the code below.

```
//div[contains(@class= 'sc-5b0433e1-5')]
```

Does anyone know how to go about this.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I'm trying to scrape the votes from SofaScore with google sheets using the importxml function.`, I cannot understand your expected value. Can I ask you about the value you want to retrieve?

Comment: @Tanaike https://i.ibb.co/5BH0Pzy/Screen-Shot-2022-05-13-at-3-09-33-AM.png I'm trying to get the data shown in the image.

Comment: @Tanaike https://i.ibb.co/SmBqbQL/Screen-Shot-2022-05-13-at-3-23-27-AM.png

Comment: Thank for replying. When I saw `https://i.ibb.co/5BH0Pzy/Screen-Shot-2022-05-13-at-3-09-33-AM.png`, it seems that you wanted to retrieve the value of 17.08%. When I saw `https://i.ibb.co/SmBqbQL/Screen-Shot-2022-05-13-at-3-23-27-AM.png`, it seems that you wanted to retrieve the value of 144. Unfortunately, when I saw the retrieved HTML, those values are not included. And, those values are put using Javascript. By this, I think that your expected values might not be able to be directly retrieved. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

JS elements are not supported by google sheets importxml formula:

[image]